# Virgule après un tiret d'incise

Tags: typographie, ponctuation, incises

Est-on autorisé à accoler une virgule directement après un tiret cadratin « fermant » une proposition incise ?

Exemple : Je me levai — allez donc savoir pourquoi —, puis partis errer Dieu sait où.

**EDIT :** Ce sujet traitait originellement du cas du point après un tiret cadratin, mais j'ai retrouvé la règle.

> Lorsque l’incise termine une phrase, on supprime le second tiret.

Comment: Bonjour ! Sujet très intéressant. Je me posais la question d'une citation mise entre tirets d'incise, s'il fallait mettre une majuscule ou non. Exemple : Le grand lui donnait constamment des claques – Est-ce que ça te plaît ? susurrait-il – et le plus petit des coups de pieds, lui meurtrissant les mollets. D'après vous, dans ce genre de phrase, met-on une majuscule à "Est-ce que" ou tout autre mot débutant la citation ? Merci de votre lumière sur le sujet.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

D'après [la-ponctuation.com](http://www.la-ponctuation.com/tirets.html) :

> Si à l'endroit où se placent les tirets d'incise, la phrase demande un signe de ponctuation, ce signe se mettra après le second tiret.

Exemple :

> Si vous aimez le chocolat – et qui ne l'aime pas ? –, ne manquez pas de visiter la fabrique non loin d'ici.

Curieusement, trouver des sources traitant de ce sujet n'est pas si facile.

**Edit:**

J'ai trouvé cet autre exemple dans [Le Courrier International](http://www.courrierinternational.com/article/2009/09/24/plus-fin-qu-hugo-chavez) :

> Mais, d’un autre côté, c’est un maniaque de l’efficacité – et de la ponctualité –, avec un goût marqué pour la technologie.

Answer (score 5):

Si on suit les [recommandations de Lacroux dans *Orthotypographie*](http://www.orthotypographie.fr/volume-II/telegramme-troncation.html) — il admet qu'il y a d'autres usages —, il faut écrire la phrase sans l'incise puis ajouter l'incise à sa place sans ajouter ni retirer de virgule.

Dans ta phrase je ne mettrai pas de virgule, préférant

> Je me levai puis partis errer Dieu sait où.

à

> Je me levai, puis partis errer Dieu sait où.

mais j'ai volontairement formulé ma première phrase de manière à avoir un exemple de « —, ».

Comment: Hum, je m'étais pourtant renseigné sur l'usage de la virgule avec le mot « puis » avant de poster mon exemple.

Comment: @Morwenn, je mettrais une virgule avant _puis_ dans une énumération, mais dans ce cas-ci non.